# How to write a RegEx that would capture a piece of a string, unless the string ends with a certain pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've started studying RegexOne, and there's a exercise in which we must capture a piece of a string until the "." , as long as the string ends with .pdf

```
match   file_a_record_file.pdf
match   file_yesterday.pdf
skip    testfile_fake.pdf.tmp
```

But I wanted to get a bit deeper and capture this piece of a string, unless the string contains more than 3 characters after a dot character "."

I tried using

```
^(\w+(?!([.](.{4,}))$))
```

but of course it didn't work. How could I correct this pattern, considering the JavaScript RegEx library? (I don't want a function, only a pattern, if that's possible).
I guess it would be more flexible if I could avoid using $, but I'd accept any answer matching the question. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `if (/\..{4}/.test(text)) { return false; }`? Or `if (/\.[^.]{4,}$/.test(text)) { return false; }`? I guess all the example strings should now match, right? If you say you want to avoid `$`, what is the right-hand match boundary in your scenario?

Comment: Sorry, I believe I haven't made myself clear. I'm not looking for a function, only for a pattern, if that's possible... I mentioned JavaScript only so that you could have a regex library in mind... Thanks for pointing out and writing this all, though!

Comment: So, does `\.[^.]{4,}$` **regex** work?

Comment: But how could I match the other lines and capture the piece I want? Unfortunatelly, this seems to only exclude the end.

Comment: With `m` flag, you make `$` match the end of any line. If you test against a single multiline string, also put `\n` into negated character class, `[^.\n]`. See https://regex101.com/r/LQFELu/2. If this matches, the result is false.

Comment: I believe this would capture exactly what I need, thanks! `^(\w*)\.[^.\n]+$`https://regex101.com/r/dNyEs2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this is what you are trying to do:

```
mySting.match(/(.*)\.pdf$/)

Match   file_a_record_file.pdf
Match   file_yesterday.pdf
null    testfile_fake.pdf.tmp
```

Edit: the string without the extension is stored on `mySting.match(/(.*)\.pdf$/)[1]`

For the 3 characters match after the first dot

```
myString.match(/^([^\.]+)\.[\w]{1,3}$/);
```

Explanation: match everything that is not a dot + match the first dot + match a word that contains 1 to 3 characters at the end of string

Comment: This works amazingly. I used `^([^\.]+)\.[\w]+$` so I could capture any number of written characters after the dot (so I would be able to get every file as long as it has only one format written, for e.g.), and got to this https://regex101.com/r/XEU3Zh/1. You also gave me the code I'd use on Javascript to store the strings as well, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could check if there are no more than 4 non dot characters after a dot.

```
^(?!.*\.[^\.\n]{4})\w+(?:\.\w+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZfxNmG/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?!.*\.[^\.\n]{4})\w+(?:\.\w+)*$/;
[
  "file_a_record_file.pdf",
  "file_yesterday.pdf",
  "testfile_fake.pdf.tmp",
  "testfile_fake.docx.tmp"
].forEach(s => {
  console.log((regex.test(s) ? "Match: " : "No match: ") + s);
});
```

If you want the part before pdf if it should end on pdf, you can use a capture group and match `.pdf` at the end.

```
^(?!.*\.[^\.\n]{4})(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\.pdf$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Re2Pmv/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?!.*\.[^.\n]{4})(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\.pdf$/;
[
  "file_a_record_file.pdf",
  "file_yesterday.pdf",
  "testfile_fake.pdf.tmp",
  "testfile_fake.docx.tmp"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is perfect. To be able not to specify the format itself after the dot, I went ahead and replaced some rules, to the point I got this
`^(?!\w+\.[^.].{4,})(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\..{3,}$`
https://regex101.com/r/pLySBZ/1

Comment: @MateusOliveira You can of course adapt the parts of the pattern to exactly what you want to allow to match.